# Exception middleware not catching exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I've created an exception handling middleware class:

```
namespace FileSharingApp.API.Middleware
{
    public class GlobalErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public GlobalErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
            }

        }

        private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
            HttpStatusCode status;

            var exceptionType = exception.GetType();

            if (exceptionType == typeof(InvalidOperationException))
            {
                status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            }
            else if (exceptionType == typeof(PasswordIncorrectException))
            {
                status = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            else
            {
                status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }

            var exceptionResult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { error = exception.Message, exception.StackTrace });
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)status;

            return context.Response.WriteAsync(exceptionResult);
        }
```

I then created an extension method to add the middleware:

```
 public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder AddGlobalErrorHandler(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
            => applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<GlobalErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
    }
```

And then called this in my program.cs class:

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.AddGlobalErrorHandler();
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

I've tested this by throwing an exception from an end point:

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> LoginUser([FromBody] LoginDto loginDto)
{
     throw new InvalidOperationException("Password is incorrect");
}
```

But the `HandleExceptionAsync` method in my middleware class is not being hit (I've added a breakpoint) and a standard 500 response is being returned to the client.

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you adding it *after* you build the application?

Comment: Yeah I am. I've updated my op with the order in which things are added

Answer (score 0):

Mine works just fine.

Maybe it's something with where you're putting app.AddGlobalErrorHandler();

Please check my github repo on https://github.com/lucasdsalves/stack-overflow-74655126

Comment: Thanks for your response. Apologies for the delay in responding. I've checked your repo but I can't see any differences. Weird. I've updated the op with the full order in which I add things in my progam.cs

Comment: Ignore me. it's because I'm using the exception handler as well as the error handler. When the exception is thrown, the exception handler error controller end point is hit and this returns a problem details response to the client. This then prevents the HandleExceptionAsync method from being triggered. I think I need to use either the exception handler or the error handling middleware class I created, but not both...